# VBA - Find number of elements in column, assuming the length can change in the future

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very, very new to VBA and am struggling to find the number of elements in a column assuming that the column's length can change in the future.

How do I find the number of rows between the start of the table and a specific string in one of the rows? i.e I would like to be able to use the number of elements as the number of iterations in a loop further in the code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses `Range.End()` method to dynamically determine the end of the column. Note that in this particular implementation your column should have more than 1 row and shouldn't have empty cells - `End` function only goes down till it finds first empty cell. If you are to add more values to this column and re-run the code -- you'll see more values printed in the Immediate console.

Note that you don't really need to know the number of elements in the column, but if you do -- you can use `Range.Rows.Count` function.

[image]

```
Sub iterateCol()

    Dim w As Worksheet
    Set w = ActiveSheet

    ' first cell in the column
    Dim rngColStart As Range
    Set rngColStart = w.[a1]

    ' this will be the range that contains all cells in the column
    Dim rngCol As Range
    Set rngCol = w.Range(rngColStart, rngColStart.End(xlDown))

    ' number of rows in the column
    Debug.Print rngCol.Rows.Count

    ' iterate through all the cells in the column
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rngCol
        Debug.Print c ' prints cell to immediate window
    Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I suppose you have columns headers so I start your items list in Row 2, then I use `Range.Find` to look for the cell where your specific string (which I called `MyString`) is and keep the row number and finally I calculate the number of iteration needed (*Last minus First + 1* so they are both taken into account in the loop)

```
Sub FindNumberOfRowsToLoopThrough()

    Dim MyString As String
    Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim NumberOfIteration As Long

    MyString = "Here it is"

    FirstRow = 2

    LastRow = Range("A:A").Find(what:=MyString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Row

    NumberOfIteration = LastRow - FirstRow + 1

    MsgBox NumberOfIteration

End Sub
```